# Github action coveralls command not found when using conda

Tags: github, environment-variables, conda, github-actions, coveralls

I am building a GitHub action that uses coveralls to report the coverage. It worked perfectly until I have specified the GitHub environment and used conda-incubator/setup-miniconda@v2 to add and test some conda dependencies.

I used the following block to run the test and call coveralls:

```
      - name: Test with pytest
        run: |
          pytest test/ --cov=MyPAckage --cov-config=.coveragerc --cov-report xml:coverage.xml

      - name: Coveralls
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          path-to-lcov: coverage.xml
        run: |
          coveralls --service=github
```

But now it raises the following error:

```
/home/runner/work/_temp/0016e5f4-2dac-4c62-95de-bdd966f80476.sh: line 3: coveralls: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

So I assume I messed up something with the environment and coveralls is not defined anymore.

I tried adding:

```
          conda install -c conda-forge coveralls
          alias coveralls='$CONDA/bin/coveralls'
```

with no success.

Here some links:

Original working version: [script](https://github.com/X-lab-3D/PANDORA/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml)  (passing)

Version with conda introduced: [script](https://github.com/X-lab-3D/PANDORA/blob/5ff13d403e0809792b19495decab62af4a462399/.github/workflows/main.yml)  [failed action](https://github.com/X-lab-3D/PANDORA/actions/runs/2998677335)

Version with coveralls installation and alias added: [script](https://github.com/X-lab-3D/PANDORA/blob/690811b527970769c332c7c8605f455e9fe4e100/.github/workflows/main.yml)  [failed action](https://github.com/X-lab-3D/PANDORA/actions/runs/2998800379)

I have also tried moving the coveralls step only to a different job of the action, but I fell into [this github issue](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26693), that causes my second job to be queued for forever, so I can't know if it worked or not.